# Show posted on date only for posts in a certain category

Tags: categories, loop

I am using a lot of custom post types throught my site and don't want to show a "posted on" date on them.

I only want date to be shown for the post in "Featured" category.

I've made some changes in loop:

swapped
`<?php twentyten_posted_on(); ?>`

with

`<?php if($category->name == 'Featured'){twentyten_posted_on();} ?>`

Now the date is gone everywhere, including the posts within "Featured" category as well... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you set `$category` and what is set to? Please post your code in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see why you want to do such a thing but it would be easier to proceed like that :

```
if( has_category('Featured') ) twentyten_posted_on();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I only need to show dates in the blog section of the wordpress CMS, the rest of post used in place of static pages and don't need any dates on them.